Source term in free-field path integral
I am currently working through deriving the Feynman propagator for free-field theory, based on chapter eight of Srednicki's book on quantum field theory. I am able to follow/rederive all of the intermediate steps in the book, except for one thing that I am hoping someone will be able to help me with.
Consider the following free-field Lagrangian density: $L_0 = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \varphi \partial^{\mu} \varphi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \varphi^2$. Using the following Fourier transformations:
$$
\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k e^{ikx} \tilde{\varphi}(k)
$$
$$
J(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k e^{ikx} \tilde{J}(k)
$$
I am able to derive an expression for the action $S_0$, which is defined as:
$$
S_0 = \int d^4x [L_0 + J \varphi] 
$$
I know that I must use different four-momenta $k$ for different terms containing $\varphi$ and/or $J$, meaning that, for example:
$$
-m^2 \varphi^2 = -\frac{m^2}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k d^4k' e^{i (k + k')_{\mu} x^{\mu}} \tilde{\varphi}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(k')
$$
If I carry through with these integrals, using the following identity:
$$
\int d^4x e^{i(k+k')_{\mu} x^{\mu}} = (2 \pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (k+k') 
$$
I get the right results for the part involving $L_0$, but I get a different result than Srednicki for the source term. Specifically, I found that:
$$
\int d^4x J(x) \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^8} \int d^4x d^4k d^4k' e^{i(k+k')_{\mu} x^{\mu}} \tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(k') = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k \tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(-k)
$$
Whereas Srednicki finds the following:
$$
\int d^4x J(x) \varphi(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d^4k \left[\tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(-k) + \tilde{J}(-k) \tilde{\varphi}(k)\right]
$$
It appears that Srednicki has the term that I derived, plus a term with the four-momenta switched between the arguments of $\tilde{J}$ and $\tilde{\varphi}$. I do not understand where this second term comes from. It feels like this might be analogous to using different four momenta for different $\varphi$ as described above, but I cannot quite grasp exactly how that reasoning would lead to this second term. Could someone perhaps explain this?

From your integral on the dirac delta you can see that (depending on whether you integrate on $k$ or $k'$): $$ \int d^4k \tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(-k) = \int d^4k' \tilde{J}(-k') \tilde{\varphi}(k')= \int d^4k \tilde{J}(-k) \tilde{\varphi}(k).$$ So $$\color{red}2 \int d^4k \tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(-k)=\int d^4k \left[\tilde{J}(k) \tilde{\varphi}(-k) + \tilde{J}(-k) \tilde{\varphi}(k)\right].$$ And if you remember that the $L_0$ contains a factor $1/2$ in front of everywhere (it's $m^2/2$ not $m^2$) while the source term does not. I think it checks out.

Thank you for the clarification. I was aware of the factor of 1/2, but I did not realise that the two integrals mentioned in your comment were equivalent. However, I realise this now. Thanks a lot for your assistance!
